# How to Extract values for Testscripts from XML Response in postman

Tags: postman-testcase

failed to capture the value of name which is "userinfo"

//this what I tried as for eg to extract the name: "userInfo"  from xml response

```
var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
pm.environment.set("name", jsonObject["methodResponse"]["params"]["param"]["value"]["struct"]["member[0].name"]);
console.log();
```

Comment: XML response is as follows

Comment: postman xml response is something like this  <methodResponse><params><param><value><struct><member><name>userInfo</name><value><struct><member><name>serverId</name><value><int>1000</int></value></member><member><name>userId</name><value><int>7654</int></value></member><member><name>userName</name><value><string>xyz</string></value></member><member><name>marketType</name><value><string>DEF</string></value></member></struct></value></member></struct></value></data></array></value></member></struct></value></param></params></methodResponse>

Comment: Please add this information to your question.